# 'glCreateShader' was not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors, glut

Why am I getting these errors?

```
error: 'GL_VERTEX_SHADER' was not declared in this scope
error: 'glCreateShader' was not declared in this scope
```

Code:

```
GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
```

And yes, I do have the includes to glut.

Comment: Have you included the openGL interface headers?

Comment: Do I need to? I thought that glut included those. It works fine for other gl commands.

Comment: You need to be running 2.0 or higher.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What does `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` return?

`CreateShader` is not in GLUT but OpenGL 2.0. If your "includes to glut" are not including `gl.h` for some reason or your GL version is less than 2.0, the headers will not declare it.

I'd also check your `gl.h` to see if `CreateShader` is actually declared there.

Edit: This OpenGL header version thing seems to be a general problem in Windows. Most people suggest using [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or another extension loader library to get around it.

Comment: `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` returns `2.0.5279 WinXP Release` It still doesn't work with an include to `gl.h` The strange thing is that `glCreateShader` is NOT in the `gl.h` Why would it not have it?

Comment: The OpenGL headers included with your compiler must be for 1.1 (or another version less than 2.0) -- which compiler are you using?

Comment: Apparently MinGW has 1.x headers, too. Updated my answer.

Comment: I setup GLEW, and included it but now I get this error: `undefined reference to '_imp____glewCreateShader'`

Comment: hmm, it's been a while since I used it. Are you linking against the appropriate library?

Comment: `#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>` that's all I'm including.

Comment: That's compiling. You need to include libraries while linking as well. Something along the lines of `-lglew`, perhaps?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. Would you mind giving me some steps?

Answer (score 4):

You need to either use an [OpenGL loading library](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) to load OpenGL functions, or [manually load the functions yourself](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions). You can't just use `gl.h` and expect to get everything.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are initializing your OpenGL context before you try to access any of the GL namespace. Eg. with GLAD:

```
// after initializing window

if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```